# KeyError using happybase because column families are returned as byte strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, hbase, happybase

I'm trying to use happybase to access my Hbase table.

I'm using the python3 branch from the happybase github repo.

Here's my test code:

```
import happybase
from settings import HBASE_THRIFT_SERVER

connection = happybase.Connection(HBASE_THRIFT_SERVER)
print(connection.tables())
table = connection.table('people')


def get_audience(audience_qual,start,end):
    row = table.row(audience_qual)
    print(row)
    return row['data:record']


def get_all_audience():
    for key, data in table.scan():
        print(key, data)


def put_people_row(row_key, people):
    table.put(row_key, {'data:record': people})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_all_audience()
    print(get_audience('daily201605180000004', 0, 0))
```

When I execute this I'm getting Key Error on the row because the column family is returned as a byte string.

```
2016-05-18 21:04:10,843 DS-Client-Dashboard INFO     Settings Loaded
[b'ambarismoketest', b'people', b'tsdb', b'tsdb-meta', b'tsdb-tree', b'tsdb-uid']
b'daily201604030000001' {b'data:': b'{"clientid":1, "customerid":23499382}'}
b'daily201605180000002' {b'data:record': b'{"clientid": 2, "customerid": 2383020475}'}
b'daily201605180000003' {b'data:record': b'{"clientid": 2, "customerid": 2383020475}'}
b'daily201605180000004' {b'data:record': b'{"clientid": 2, "customerid": 2383020475}'}
{b'data:record': b'{"clientid": 2, "customerid": 2383020475}'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user100/ds_one_api/app/V1/hbase_operations.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(get_audience('daily201605180000004', 0, 0))
  File "/home/user100/ds_one_api/app/V1/hbase_operations.py", line 12, in get_audience
    return row['data:record']
KeyError: 'data:record'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Happybase documentation does not show any conversion to get column families working. However, it does mention that HBase stores data as byte strings which happybase cannot handle.

How do I return a column family from a row without Key Error?

Answer (score 1):

```
    return row[b'data:record']
```

Works fine.